# Surveys/monographs on the vortex filament equation

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

Where can I find surveys on the mathematical aspects of the *vortex filament equation*?

In particular, I'm interested in the following topics:

- physical motivation;
- notion of solutions and wellposedness;
- relationship with the Schrödinger equation;
- relationship with Euler and Navier-Stokes equations;
- formation of singularities.

---

**Note 1.** Vortex filament equation: $$\partial_t \chi = \partial_s \chi \wedge \partial_{ss} \chi,$$
where $\chi(t,s)$ is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$.

**Note 2.** Related questions have been asked at the following links:

- [Derivation of the vortex filament equation from Euler equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331609/derivation-of-the-vortex-filament-equation-from-euler-equation),
- [Relationship between the vortex filament equation and the cubic Schrödinger equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331614/relationship-between-the-vortex-filament-equation-and-the-cubic-schr%C3%B6dinger-equa),
- [Relationship between the vortex filament equation and the transport equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331621/relationship-between-the-vortex-filament-equation-and-the-transport-equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book by Majda and Bertozzi would seem to have some of what you're looking for https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/vorticity-and-incompressible-flow/393C35E544EDD0711CAA7F7AB05D7432

This paper by Jerrard and Seis also has some more recent work on weak solutions to the vortex filament equation https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00227.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of references where the equation has been studied from the point of view and with the techniques of differential geometry?