# Derivation of the vortex filament equation from Euler equation

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

How can the vortex filament equation 
$$\partial_t \chi = \partial_s \chi \wedge \partial_{ss} \chi,$$
where $\chi(t,s)$ is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$,
be derived from the Euler equation 
$$\partial_t \omega + v\cdot \nabla \omega = \omega \cdot \nabla v, \quad \operatorname{div} v = 0,$$
where $v:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$, and $\omega = \operatorname{curl}(v):\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3.$

---

I've asked a more general question at [Survey on the vortex filament equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331539/survey-on-the-vortex-filament-equation).

Comment: you can find a detailed derivation in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00227 .

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you. That's very helpful.