# Relationship between the vortex filament equation and the cubic Schrödinger equation

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

How is the vortex filament equation 
$$\partial_t \chi = \partial_s \chi \wedge \partial_{ss} \chi,$$
where $\chi(t,s)$ is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$,
related to the cubic Schrödinger equation?

---

**Note 1.** I've asked a more general question at [Survey on the vortex filament equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331539/survey-on-the-vortex-filament-equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are, respectively, the curvature and torsion of $\gamma$, and one defines the wave function $\psi=\kappa\exp\left(i\int \tau\,dx\right)$, then $\psi$ satisfies the nonlinear (cubic) Schrödinger equation [1,2,3]
$$-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\tfrac{1}{2}|u|^2 u.$$

[1] H. Hasimoto, [A soliton on a vortex filament](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/soliton-on-a-vortex-filament/1A2FF58DD1B8DE20509866A4713531F3) (1972).
[2] N. Koiso, [The vortex filament equation and a semilinear Schrödinger equation in a Hermitian symmetric space](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200787341) (1997).
[3] D.D. Holm and S.N. Stechmann, [Hasimoto transformation and
vortex soliton motion driven by fluid helicity](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/27b6/70827041e81a3f7b407386589f4a287602d5.pdf) (2004).

Comment: Thank you. I've checked those references. They are really helpful. I've just an additional question: what is the physical meaning of that wave function $\psi$? That is, physically, why does the soliton ansatz of considering $\psi$ connect the vortex filament equation and the Schroedinger one?

Comment: it is a mathematical mapping of two unrelated physical problems, one problem from classical physics, the other from quantum physics; there is only a mathematical relation, no physics relation.