# Wellposedness results for the cubic Schödinger equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

Motivated by the question [Relationship between the vortex filament equation and the cubic Schrödinger equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331614/relationship-between-the-vortex-filament-equation-and-the-cubic-schr%C3%B6dinger-equa), 
I'd like to ask the following:

Where can I find a reference on wellposedness results for the cubic Schödinger equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite an extensive literature on this topic:

[On the one-dimensional cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2073) (2010)

[Global well-posedness of the cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equation on compact manifolds without boundary](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2826) (2010)

[Almost sure well-posedness of the cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2820) (2009)

[Global well-posedness for cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4642) (2009)

[Unconditional Uniqueness Results for the cubic Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.10631) (2018)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any comprehensive monograph that deals with the semilinear Schrödinger equation?

Comment: Semilinear Schrödinger Equations: https://bookstore.ams.org/cln-10